# git rebase когда кто-то залил твой коммит в общую ветку

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

Есть вот такая история коммитов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Антон создал себе ветку `iss1` от `master` и сделал там два коммита **4** и **5**. В свою очередь Вадим решает начать свою работу, взяв некоторые наработки Антона из коммита **4**. Вадим делает коммит **6** и мержит свою ветку `iss2` в `master`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Антону неведомо, что кто-то отбренчивался от его ветки. Проходит день и перед продолжением работы над фичей, Антон решает взять себе свежие изменения из `master` с помощью rebase.

---

Я правильно понимаю, что это один из случаев, когда Антону нельзя делать rebase на `master`, так как один из его коммитом **4** уже попал в общую ветку `master`?

---

### Обновление

Мне стоило отметь, что на тот момент, когда Антон планирует делать rebase, Вадим уже сделал свой merge, то есть, изменения коммита **4** уже в `master`.

Cогласен с авторами ответов внизу, что технически, rebase выполнить можно и возможно даже без конфликтов. Вопрос касается того, не нарушается ли тут, каким-то образом то самое золотое правило ["Не следует делать rebase общей ветки"](https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/352640/)?

Comment: Если rebase будет только 5 коммита, и от него в данный момент никто не отбранчивался, то последствий, по моему мнению, не будет. Нельзя трогать 4 коммит.

Comment: *Вопрос касается того, не нарушается ли тут, каким-то образом то самое золотое правило "Не следует делать rebase общей ветки"?* — из того, что описано по ссылке, сделан автором явно неверный вывод. **не делать** надо «push --force» (а не «rebase»). и, если уж так страшат ветвления, то **не делать** их (т.е., как раз наоборот: вместо «merge» делать «rebase»).

Comment: Rebase делается от конкретного коммита вправо по цепочке. Хеши всех этих коммитов пересчитываются. Если кто-то от любого из этих коммитов отбранчивался, то у него будут проблемы. Чтобы этого избежать можно работать только с коммитом 5, его можно перебазировать на 7 или 6. Это не нарушит "золотое правило".

Comment: @AlexR. *Если кто-то от любого из этих коммитов отбранчивался, то у него будут проблемы*. нельзя ли привести пример этих «проблем»?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin как раз те самые которые описываются в статье. Допустим вы перебазировались и у вас коммит 5'. Но у ваших последователей в локальном репозитории все еще коммит 5. При пуши в сетевой они получать ошибку. В общем для них тоже нет ничего страшного, нужно им выкачать новый репозиторий и сделать Rebase у себя. Но по опыту могу сказать, что новичков это вгоняет в ступор, т.к. ситуация очень  не очевидная и ненаглядная (визуально) при анализе.

Comment: @AlexR. *как раз те самые которые описываются в статье* — как я уже написал выше, проблемой в статье является команда "push --force", а не команда "rebase". *При пуши в сетевой они получать ошибку* — я же в своём ответе даже демонстрацию привёл: никакой ошибки при использовании "rebase" нет. // опишите, пожалуйста, хотя бы, например, дополнив ваш ответ, ситуацию, в которой возникнут **реальные** проблемы при использовании команды "rebase".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Я правильно понимаю, что это один из случаев, когда Антону нельзя делать rebase на master, так как один из его коммитом 4 уже попал в общую ветку master?

вопросов, собственно, три:

1. коммит действительно попал в ветку `master`?

   ответ вполне очевиден из описания: да, конечно попал.
2. что произойдёт если выполнить команду *rebase* в описанной ситуации?

   давайте проверим:

   1. создаём три коммита:

      ```
      $ git log --oneline origin/master
      e71c5c3 (origin/master) 3
      23b42ba 2
      5ed114a 1
      ```
   2. из коммита `23b42ba` делаем ветку `iss1` и добавляем ещё пару коммитов:

      ```
      $ git log --oneline origin/iss1 
      117ae92 (origin/iss1) 5
      8c59be3 4
      23b42ba 2
      5ed114a 1
      ```
   3. из коммита `8c59be3` делаем ветку `iss2` и добавляем ещё один коммит:

      ```
      $ git log --oneline origin/iss2
      f2ff6a4 (origin/iss2) 6
      8c59be3 4
      23b42ba 2
      5ed114a 1
      ```
   4. делаем слияние `iss2` в `master`:

      ```
      $ git log --oneline origin/master
      b719862 (origin/master) Merge branch 'iss2'
      f2ff6a4 (origin/iss2) 6
      8c59be3 4
      e71c5c3 (master) 3
      23b42ba 2
      5ed114a 1
      ```
   5. и вот мы приблизились к критической точке. барабанная дробь. переключаемся на `iss1` и выполняем команду *rebase*:

      ```
      $ git checkout iss1
      $ git rebase master
      First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
      Applying: 4
      Applying: 5
      ```

   никаких ошибок, катастроф и оторванных конечностей. барабанная дробь сконфуженно прерывается. коммиты отлично уживаются друг с другом:

   ```
   $ git log --oneline --all --graph 
   * 1a2d0f6 (HEAD -> iss1) 5
   * 4bd022f 4
   | *   b719862 (origin/master) Merge branch 'iss2'
   | |\  
   |/ /  
   | * f2ff6a4 (origin/iss2) 6
   * | e71c5c3 (master) 3
   | | * 117ae92 (origin/iss1) 5
   | |/  
   | * 8c59be3 4
   |/  
   * 23b42ba 2
   * 5ed114a 1
   ```

   всё, расходимся.
3. можно ли выполнять в таком случае команду *rebase*?

   вот тут объективного ответа, увы, нет. зато есть абсолютно объективный встречный вопрос: а в честь чего, собственно, может быть «нельзя»?

Comment: Обновил вопрос согласно Вашим замечаниям.

Answer (score 0):

Сама функция *rebase* таких, как вы описываете ограничений, не имеет. Если очень просто, то она сравнивает изменения, которые необходимо оставить относительно нового коммита.

Здесь есть несколько вариантов, смотря какие цели вы преследуете. Самой простой случай, это перебазировать 5 коммит на 7, но в этом случае потеряется часть вашей история по 4 коммиту. Вы все еще останитесь автором коммита, но работы по *iss1* начнуться как бы позже. Если работы завершены, то можно делать *Merge*, в этом случае изменения 4 коммита не будут отражаться в разнице 8 коммита.

Немного другой пример, если, допустим, не было бы 6 комиита, но изменения комитов 3 и 4 были бы одинаковыми, то ситуация была бы очень похожая.

Нужно поэкспеременировать на локальном репозитории, чтобы понять какая стратегия нужна. Например, TortoiseGit умеет делать и *Rebase* и *Merge*.

На всякий случай оставлю ссылку на [статью](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-Git-%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Формально по рисунку сам 4 коммит не попал в ветку `master`, а попали только его изменения.

Comment: *Формально по рисинку сам 4 коммит не попал в ветку master* — попал. // хоть «формально», хоть «неформально» (не знаю, что это значит).

Comment: К чему ваш комментари? Он несет какую-то новую информацию? Нет. Тогда зачем он? В ветке с желтыми кружками цифры 4 нет. Это означает, что коммит 4 делался не из ветки master. Я хотел отметил лишь это. Есть варианты, когда он могу туда попасть. На ответ самой задачи это не сильно влияет, но может пригодится. Сам ответ простой - rebase делать можно.

Comment: ветка в git – это не последовательность коммитов, а **указатель** на один-единственный коммит. потому «нахождение» коммита «в» ветке (как и «вне» её) строго говоря не имеет смысла, но вполне можно подразумевать под этим «коммит является одним из предков того коммита, на который указывает ветка»

Comment: Обновил вопрос согласно Вашим замечаниям.